# JQuery input mask fails when load or create a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-inputmask

I'm doing an application using RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask.

All works well, except when load or create a dynamic fields

```
<html>
...
<div> 
    <input class="datemask" value="31/01/2014" name="fechaPago[]" id="fechaPago[]" type="text">
</div>
//More ajax loaded fields

<h:commandLink action="#{someaction}">
    <f:ajax onevent="function(data) { configureMask() }"/>
    Click Here
</h:commandLink>

...
<script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        configureMask();
    });
    function configureMask() {
        $(".datemask").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});
    }
    //]]>
</script>
...
</html>
```

When the action is executed, only new fields are loaded and a success callback tries to configure all fields with the mask, including new fields, but previous fields doesn't work. All previous fields are empty and do not accept new value.

How can configure the loaded fields without affect the previous fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do since you didn't say what you want to happen -- but let's give it a shot.

Each time your link is clicked, it will evoke the `configureMask` function.  This function selects ALL input elements in the DOM and initializes the `inputmask`.

Is it your intent to re-initialize all input elements each time this link is clicked?  Once the `inputmask` has been initialized, you don't need to do anything else other then update the value.  It's possible that this could be messing something up, if you're trying to initialize an `inputmask` that has already been initialized.

You can remove the old inputmask on the element if you want, and then re-initialize them, but that doesn't make any sense.

```
$(".datemask").inputmask('remove');
```

I feel like what you're trying to do is initialize the `inputmask` for the injected element.

```
...
<h:commandLink action="#{someaction}">
    <f:ajax onevent="function(data) { configureMask(this) }"/>
    Click Here
</h:commandLink>
...
function configureMask(element) {
    //if the element was passed in then select it, else select all 
    //elements that have not been processed
    var $elements = element ? $(element) : $(".datemask").not(".datemask-processed");
    $elements.inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy").addClass("datemask-processed");
}
```

Since you're already using the `jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js` library, you have access to all of the default date definitions.  You don't need to send in the placeholder for the `dd\mm\yyyy`, because it's already defined.

```
//snippet from the `jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js` library
$.extend($.inputmask.defaults.aliases, { 
        'dd/mm/yyyy': { 
            mask: "1/2/y", 
            placeholder: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This was also helpful for my case:

```
$(".phone-input").inputmask();
$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(e){
    $(".phone-input").inputmask();
});
```